# SQL Case inside In Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, in-operator

What is wrong with query?

```
select * 
from ERP.dbo.Table 
where storeID in (case 
                     when @Designation = 80 
                        then 
                           (select storeID 
                            from ERP.dbo.Store 
                            where companyID = @CompanyID 
                              and isMonitoringAvailable = 1  
                              and storeID = ISNULL(@StoreId, storeID)) 
                        else 
                           (select storeID 
                            from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole 
                            where employeeID = @EmployeeId 
                              and storeID = ISNULL(@StoreId,storeID) )  
                 end)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery 
>   follows =, !=, <, <= ,>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Hi, did you test my suggestion below? Is it satisfactory for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can re write your condition below way

```
select * from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole where
  ( storeID in (          
  (select storeID 
     from ERP.dbo.Store 
    where companyID=@CompanyID and isMonitoringAvailable=1  
      and storeID=ISNULL(@StoreId,storeID)
        ) and @Designation=80
    ) Or
   storeID  in (Select storeID 
           from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole 
          where employeeID=@EmployeeId 
            and storeID=ISNULL(@StoreId,storeID)
               )
```

Your query return error because then and else result generate multiple storeid

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` expects [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), hence the error. A performance-wise alternative is to use a `UNION ALL` operator like this:

```
select * from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole 
where @Designation=80 AND storeID in (  
    select storeID 
    from ERP.dbo.Store 
    where companyID=@CompanyID and isMonitoringAvailable=1  
    and storeID=ISNULL(@StoreId,storeID)
)
UNION ALL
select * from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole 
where @Designation<>80 AND storeID in (  
    select storeID 
    from ERP.dbo.EmployeeRole 
    where employeeID=@EmployeeId 
    and storeID=ISNULL(@StoreId,storeID)
)
```

Another approach would be to use `IF-ELSE`, but the `UNION ALL` would be better.